# Set MacFUSE options with EncFS and password from stdin

Tags: mac, command-line, encryption, macfuse

Today I set up an EncFS volume and I want to automate it as much as possible. I discovered that I can pass the password via stdin with the `-S` switch:

```
echo sekret | encfs -S ~/encrypted JC /Volumes/encrypted
```

In addition to that I want to pass additional parameters to MacFUSE like the volume name:

```
encfs ~/encrypted /Volumes/encrypted -- -o volname=Encrypted
```

The combination of both colides. Is there a way to specify MacFUSE options and to pass the parameter from stdin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the `-o` argument without passing `--` first, i.e.

```
echo sekret | encfs -S ~/encrypted /Volumes/encrypted -o volname=Encrypted
```

will do the trick.